# Assuming perceptual realism, if there exists a red apple, and I am thinking of it, is the thing in my mind red?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, realism, perception

Is there a thing in my mind? Is that how it's phrased? I understand there is the definition of apple as a concept...is this what is in my mind? The definition doesn't include red though...Honestly I would have said that if there is a thing and I'm thinking about it, there are two different entities, there is the real thing that exists and there is the concept of it in my mind, but this doesn't seem to be correct. Can anyone please tell me what actually is in my mind? Is it called a concept? Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

According to [representationalism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/perception-contents/), which is probably the most popular philosophical approach to perception these days, when you perceive a red apple, you token a *representation* of the apple. This representation, which is the percept itself or a related entity, represents the apple, in the sense that it will typically have accuracy conditions that are sensitive to the apple---say, the representation will be false, or inaccurate, if it represents the apple as red but it is green.

Now, many, although by no means all, philosophers will say that perceptual representations are [non-conceptual](https://plato.stanford.edu/search/r?entry=/entries/content-nonconceptual): they are not constituted by concepts, at least if concepts are taken to be the same entities we think and judge with. Perceptual representations earn their accuracy conditions in some other way, perhaps simply by *tracking* extramental states of affairs.

In any event, you are perfectly right: when you think of, or perceive, an existing red apple, there are two things: a mental state of yours that *represents* the apple, and the apple out there. Only the latter is red; the formerly merely *represents* the apple as being red.

Comment: I think his question is what [direct realists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Na%C3%AFve_realism), who are *not* representationalists, have to say about "things in the head". In other words, when they say that we perceive the apple's redness *directly* is that redness only "out there" into which our mind "spills over", or is there also something "in the mind", and if so is it red itself?

Comment: He might indeed be alluding to naïve realism. On the other hand, the way he describes the position he has in mind (no pun intended), it is more naturally understood as representationalism, or perhaps a sense-data account. Hopefully he'll clarify.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies, they are very helpful. I'm writing a paper about Anselm's ontological argument, Kant and Plantingas objections. Kant speaks of the concept of $100 and how it is unaffected if the $100 actually exists in reality. (hence: existence is not a predicate) Anselm speaks of the greatest conceivable being, says 'if it exists in the mind', ...can this being actually exist in the mind? Does the $100 actually exist in the mind? According to both Kant and Anselm, it seems they have distinguished between two entities, one in the mind and one in reality, is this typical?

Comment: @RobHv The clear distinction between "subjective" impressions and "real" things is often attributed to Descartes in modern times, but one can detect it already in Aristotle, Stoics, and medieval authors like Anselm. Frege codified it in his semantics as the distinction between [sense and reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sense_and_reference).

Comment: Reading that "The reference of a sentence is its truth value, its sense is the thought that it expresses" , I don't think this is what I'm after, it's not the semantics, the truth value or meaning of a sentence that I'm wanting to know about, it's the object vs concept. I know we define concepts and then there may be instances of that concept, but does this mean if there is a red apple in reality, and I think of the red apple, that there is a 'red apple in my mind'? Or is it the concept that has the definition of apple that is in my mind? I'm confused...sorry I hope I've been clear

Comment: @RobHv "The reference of a proper name is the object it means or indicates, its sense is what the name expresses". You need not worry about reference of a sentence being its truth value, Frege needed that for technical reasons. On Frege's view sense/concept is not (just) in your mind, it is "objective", and of course it does not naively share the properties of its referent. You could say it is what allows to establish truth values of sentences about "red", and it need not involve anything literally red any more than a photosensor does.

Comment: Thanking you muchly, so the referent is the real apple and the sense is whatever is in my mind...see the thing is, i was told by my lecturer that the thing in my mind is actually not itself "red", but i was thinking, then its not really an "apple" either, but it does make sense in general conversation to say 'i have the apple in my mind'

Comment: AFAIK, lengthy discussions in the comment section are frowned upon in SE. Perhaps better if you take this to a chat room.

Comment: Is there a chat room on Stack Exchange, where we may discuss at length?

Comment: There is! https://chat.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think this is way over my head, I really need to study some Frege and some other philosophers, I've posted in the chat forum, if you could join me conifold, I'd love that.